# javax.ws.rs.core.Response build fails to retain object's information

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I was trying to implement a rest call. the front end get:

```
[{},{}]
```

---

Resource code:

```
@Component
@Path(ResourcePaths.ROOT_PATH)
public class VideoResource {

    @Autowired
    private ReadVideoService readVideoService;

    @GET
    @Path(ResourcePaths.POPULAR)
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response getVideo() {

        ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.status(Response.Status.OK);
        List<Video> videos = readVideoService.getAllVideos();

        //GenericEntity<List<Video>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Video>>(videos);

        //here it is able to print class info(from class member value)
        System.out.println(videos.get(0).toString() +" "+ videos.get(1).toString());

        return responseBuilder.entity(videos).build();
    }

}
```

but the below line is able to print the info of the objects returned from service layer.

```
System.out.println(videos.get(0).toString() +" "+ videos.get(1).toString());
```

So I guess the problem is at this line:

```
return responseBuilder.entity(videos).build();
```

I also tried to use **GenericEntity**:

```
GenericEntity<List<Video>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Video>>(videos);
```

but it result in following error, I don't understand what **java.lang.reflect.Type** is referring to:

```
Error:(37, 45) java: constructor GenericEntity in class javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.List<com.mondo.mondo_service.rest.model.Video>,java.lang.reflect.Type
  found: java.util.List<com.mondo.mondo_service.rest.model.Video>
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

This is service layer:

```
@Component
public class ReadVideoService {

    @Autowired
    public VideoDao videoDao;
    public List<Video> getAllVideos() {
        return videoDao.findAll();
    }

}
```

This is dao object:

```
@Repository
public class VideoDao extends BaseDao<Video> {

    public List<Video> findAll() {
        Session database = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Query taskQuery = database.createQuery("select v from Video v");
        List<Video> videos = taskQuery.list();

        database.close();
        return videos;
    }

}
```

Entity object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "md_video")
public class Video implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String url;
    private int duration;
    private String img;
    private String source;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

--------------update---------------

I tried to decompose below line into three line:

```
return responseBuilder.entity(videos).build();
```

to

```
responseBuilder = responseBuilder.entity(videos);
Response res = responseBuilder.build();
return res;
```

Strangely I found in the second case when it reaches **return res;**  the Response object **res** still contains all the entity information. Then why the information lost after it is returned?

[image]

Comment: try `Response.ok().entity()).build(videos);` in the return statement.

Comment: Tried Response.ok().entity(videos).build(); still doesn't work.

Comment: did you try putting debugger and see the content of response object ?

Comment: Hi @AmitK, I had some updates at the bottom, could you please take a look again?

Comment: Issue might be on front end as response object contains the data assuming you are returning data from your resource directly , it might be getting lost somewhere while parsing... you can also check the tcp dump and see whether the data is passed to the network or not ?

Comment: What if you try to change it to `public Response<List<Video>> getVideo()`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I didn't have getters and setters in my entity object. After I added getters and setters, entity info gets returned properly.